# Admob NativeAd showing blank when i scroll Recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads, firebase-admob

I have added `NativeAd` in `RecyclerView` with `MediaView` (Open bidding + Admob).

Sometimes when I am scrolling a list. video ad showing blank with white color. but image ads loading perfectly.

> Main issue is when scroll recycler view then displays blank video in media view.

*Below AdMob libraries are used in application*

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.2.0'**

**implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.5.0.0'**

> here I have attached an image of how looks like the screen when showing a blank video.
> if anyone has faced this type of issue or gets resolved then please give a hint or solution.

[image]

-----------------Edit-------------------

1. I have found the actual problem for displaying native ads in recycler view.

- I m using viewpager in my application and the same native ad show in 2 pager fragments so If in Screen A display NativeAd1 and same NaiveAd display in Screen B then showing the blank view as above image.

Comment: Hello, I need your help. I'm trying to add Native Advanced Ads with RecyclerView. But some home I'm facing some issue. Can you share your code here, how to implement it. I'm using API level 20.2.0. Please help me If it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. No Problem. If is it possible whenever, please share.

Comment: Hi, @SumitPansuriya I am also facing the same issue. in my case when I am showing the same native ad in two placements that time issue is occurring. Like I have shown a native ad in activity & also show in a dialog of that activity. both native ad objects are the same.

Comment: Hi, @axita.savani I am also facing the same issue with video ads.

Answer (score 0):

What does your code to load the native ad look like? Are you by any chance calling [NativeAdOptions.shouldReturnUrlsForImageAssets()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/formats/NativeAdOptions#shouldReturnUrlsForImageAssets()) on your request?

If you call that method, and image ads returned, you'll need to call [MediaContent.setMainImage()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MediaContent#setMainImage(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) on the returned ad's media content in order for the image ad to be displayed.

Comment: I m not using ```NativeAdOptions.shouldReturnUrlsForImageAssets()``` this method.But i m check when MediaConent is Video then set that Conent. Also Not used "MediaContent.setMainImage()" this.